# Angular 5 image not loading in url() but loads in src

Tags: css, visual-studio, webpack, background-image, angular5

The same image does not show up when I use it in url() css function but it shows up in image src :

```
<div style="width:278px;height:52px;background-image:url('..\assets/bg.png')">

</div> <--- this does not work
<img src="..\assets/bg.png" /> <----this works
```

In output html, the div tag path remains untouched and get a 404 error but the img tag src is converted to base64 (which is wired) and works

Comment: Provide jsfiddle to look at live code.